# AutoMapper and IDataReader

Tags: c#, automapper, idatareader, automapper-6

I would like to map data from `IDateReader` to some class but can not do it simply.  I wrote the following code:

```
 cfg.CreateMap<IDataReader, MyDto>()
      .ForMember(x => x.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(rdr => rdr["Id"]))
      .ForMember(x => x.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(rdr => rdr["Name"]))
      .ForMember(x => x.Text, opt => opt.MapFrom(rdr => rdr["Text"]));
```

UPD: I tried to use Automapper.Data from Nuget but it depends on 
NETStandard.Library but I use .NET Framework 4.5
But this way is bad for me because I have to describe mapping rule for each column. Is it possible to avoid describing all of these rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `ITypeConverter`, such as the following:

```
public class DataReaderConverter<TDto> : ITypeConverter<IDataReader, TDto> where TDto : new
{
    public TDto Convert(IDataReader source, TDto destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (destination == null)
        {
            destination = new TDto();
        }

        typeof(TDto).GetProperties()
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(property => property.SetValue(destination, source[property.Name]));
    }
}


cfg.CreateMap<IDataReader, MyDto>().ConvertUsing(new DataReaderConverter<MyDto>());
```